# Why <sys/uio.h> called 'UIO' instead of 'VIO'

Tags: history, linux-headers

As [The Open Group doc](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_uio.h.html) says, the `<sys/uio.h>` header defines the `iovec` structure, so why we call it Berkeley `UIO.h` rather than `V(ector)IO.h`?

Answer (score 2):

The naming convention can be a little arbitrary from time to time.  In this particular instance the `uio` stands for **Unix i/o**.  There are also many other examples with this matching convention.  To name a couple `unistd.h` and `unistr.h`

Wouldn't you expect it to be `sys/iov.h` and not `sys/vio.h` anyways to keep consistent with the variable names?

[Unix Specifications](http://www.redwoodsoft.com/%7Edru/unixbook/book.chinaunix.net/special/ebook/addisonWesley/APUE2/0201433079/ch14lev1sec7.html#ch14lev1sec7)